# How made var DateTime global variable

Tags: c#

How to make `newTime` as a global variable?

It should be added 30 minutes in time and use it in a condition. It is necessary to make var newTime  as global var.

```
 if (timerCheck == 0)
    {

        var today = DateTime.Now;

        var interval = new TimeSpan(00, 30, 00);

        var newTime = today + interval;

        timerCheck = 1;
    }
    if (timerCheck == 1) 
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now;

        if (today >= newTime) 
        {
```

Comment: declare that variable outside the method?

Comment: Put it in outer scope.

Comment: You may want to read up on scope [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static DateTime NewTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
if (today >= GlobalVariables.NewTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move it outside if.
I don't test it, but It might work.

```
DateTime newTime;
if (timerCheck == 0)
{

    var today = DateTime.Now;

    var interval = new TimeSpan(00, 30, 00);

    newTime = today + interval;

    timerCheck = 1;
}
if (timerCheck == 1) 
{
    if (newTime.Equals(default(DateTime)) return; // don't sure is it required or not

    var today = DateTime.Now;

    if (today >= newTime) 
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you should put it outside the body of If first as a variable then use it in the condition.